# My iOS app cannot locate my plist in code

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, plist

I am doing [this tutorial](http://rshankar.com/uicollectionview-demo-in-swift/)

There is a plist in it that provides a datasource for a collectionView with some data. I have the plist in a folder called Resources:

[image]

The name property of the plist items is the name of the images to be displayed, so that is why the names do not correspond to fruit, as my images are of clothing icons. This function here does not make it past the first if statement. Why could this be?

```
 func populateData() {
        if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(
            "Fruits", ofType: "plist") {
                if let dictArray = NSArray(contentsOfFile: path) {
                    for item in dictArray {
                        if let dict = item as? NSDictionary {
                            let name = dict["name"] as! String
                            let group = dict["group"] as! String

                            let fruit = Fruit(name: name, group: group)
                            if !contains(groups, group){
                                groups.append(group)
                            }
                            fruits.append(fruit)
                        }
                    }
                }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you enable the target membership of your Fruits.plist file? You can do it by opening the Fruits.plist file and checking the box for your app in the File Inspector.

Comment: @blobbfuesch That solved it thank you. The target membership was set to my tests folder so I just checked the checkbox that says my app name, rather than the tests. Thanks.